# Auto-increment counter in SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL Server, I have used MySQL (basic development). Now I wanted to create a table in my SQL Server which does auto-increment/-decrement depends up on addition and deletion of rows.

And to create a table I found this one. example and I create my database but it is not working as that good.

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
   ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
   LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   FirstName varchar(255),
   Address varchar(255),
   City varchar(255)
)
```

When I delete any rows still my ID should be decrement from `2-1 or 6-5 or 7-6` And Some time it automatically Increment from `7-9 or 6-9`. And It does not work perfectly.

So can any one tell me how solve this problem I was trying nearly for 24hrs upto now and end up with no results.

Please help how to solve this.

Comment: Once an `Identity` has been used, it's used.  I've never seen MS SQL automatically decrease an `auto incrementing` column when a record is deleted.  You'll have to maintain this column yourself.

Comment: "Reusing" or "recycling" ID values that have been used before is a **horribly bad** idea - and therefore, SQL Server doesn't do it - and that's a ***GOOD thing!***

Answer (score 1):

Performance would be horrible - and will wih a trigger. a 1 row deletion can turn into a 100 million row update followed by a billion rows cascading updates. It is a horrible design.

And that is why NO database supports that (including MySQL).

The ID is sued up when used up and a primary key should never change on a whim's notice. Imaginge you have a million rows and delete ro2 nr 2 - that is 999997 updates followed by updating all rows that use that row in a foreign key constraint.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, SQL Server doesn't have a mechanism that updates automatically an IDENTITY column once some rows are deleted. I think a mechanism of this type could also make the performance worse and for this reason a task of this type is not performed.

The first simple task that comes to my mind is a [trigger](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx), listening to the deletions of the rows. Once a deletion has been made, the trigger would update the IDENTITY column accordingly. But, you have to understand that the performance of your SQL Server instance would be horrible, considering for example an update of 1 million rows.

Comment: That trigger is a really, really, horribly bad idea... don't do it, and don't recommend it to others, ***please*** !

Comment: @marc_s I believe that the user has already thought something about it. Mine is not recommendation, otherwise I wouldn't have added a note about, as final result, the issue related to the performance and the updates.

Answer (score 0):

Identity property results in gaps in column values as rows are deleted . Even if insertion is being done and insertion fails then also the identity column value gets incremented and is not rolled back .

If you really want consecutive values you should mantain a seperate table containing current maximum value and update it as rows are inserted and deleted.

You can create a stored procedure to implement custom sequencing logic in which a table containing a single row and column is updated according to the parameter passed to stored procedure which indicates whether insertion is being done or deletion.
[See here for more](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/should-i-use-identity-or-not)

Answer (score -1):

In SQL Server, IDENTITY column value does not get decremented when a record is deleted. That is how it works. This is imposed constraint on IDENTITY column to be thread safe.

So I think in your case, let the IDENTITY column be as it is. In case you want a serial number to be attached with rows based on primary key, you can use ROW_NUMBER() when you do a SELECT from the table like this:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) as rn, * FROM your_table
```

Comment: Actually it has nothing to do with thread safety - you can do that perfectly find in transaction safely, albeit with horrific performance. Factually wrong.

Comment: what I think the database designers might not have chosen to decrement an identity column when a record is deleted because of issues it might create in maintaining uniqueness of the column values in case of concurrent transactions. @tomtom, can you give an insight?

Comment: Yes. Incompetend db designer. I Know, sounds horrible. Still. Generally seen as a non-standard and shitty design due to the implications of deletions in the middle. An Id is a system level column, nota business locig thing. Should not be used otherwise.